# How to copy and paste data, in lots of 200, from horizontal to vertical?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste data from horizontal to vertical from sheet1 to sheet3 in a lots of 200.

Say I have a list of 600 tickers. The code will copy the first 200 from sheet1 cells ("C6 till GT7") and paste it vertically in sheet3 cell A2.

I need the next lot of 200 appended in sheet3 after row 201.

My code is pasting only the last 200 in sheet 3.

[image]

[image]

```vb
Sub getbulkprices()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim r, iLastRow As Long, plr as long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    iLastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A500").ClearContents
  
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:B500000").ClearContents
     
    For r = 2 To ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 200
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Resize(200).Value = _
          ws1.Cells(r, 1).Resize(200).Value
                  
        ws.Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "=@RHistory(R2C1:R200C1,"".Timestamp;.Close"",""NBROWS:""&R2C2&"" INTERVAL:1D"",,""SORT:ASC TSREPEAT:NO CH:In;"",R[5]C)"
        Application.Run "EikonRefreshWorksheet"
                
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
               
        plr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
               
        ws.Range("D6:IK7").Copy
               
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:B" & plr + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
          :=False, Transpose:=True
              
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.StatusBar = r & " / " & iLastRow - 1
    Next r
          
End Sub
```

Comment: The paste specification always starts in row 2, where A2 is the target beginning of the range:
**ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:B" & plr + 1).PasteSpecial**

Comment: i am also using the same in the code, isnt it ?

Comment: @Rahul Vaidya `ws.Range("D6:IK7").Copy` copies the same range in each pass of the loop. Is this what you want, i.e., to paste transpose the same values multiple times? Also, your post specifies 200 rows (`Range("C6:GT7")`) but `Range("DK6:IK7")` includes 242 columns. Rather than looping, would it work the same for you to paste transpose the entire copied range to `Sheet3!A2` and `Range().Insert xlShiftDown` at row 400 then at row 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider qualifying the `Rows.Count` to the that *same* worksheet as qualifier to `.Cells` in the `plr` assignment:

```vb
plr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells( _
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count, 1 _
      ).End(xlUp).Row
```

Even better situate the copy and paste inside a `With` block to avoid repetition of worksheet:

```vb
For r = 2 To ... Step 200
    ...

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
        plr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
        ws.Range("D6:IK7").Copy
               
        .Range(.Cells(plr + 1, 1), _ 
               .Cells(plr + 200, 2) _
        ).PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, _
            Transpose:=True
   End With

   ...
Next r
```

Consider even `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` and avoid copy/paste:

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    plr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
          
    .Range(.Cells(plr + 1, 1), _ 
           .Cells(plr + 200, 2) _
    ) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("D6:IK7"))
End With
```

Comment: Hi Parfait, i have tried your suggestion, out of 672 total tickers only 72 got pasted in sheet 3, am i missing something here ?

Comment: Which suggestion? After assigning `plr`, run `Debug.Print plr` and check Immediate Window (Ctrl/Cmd + G). Does the variable increase with each loop iteration?

Comment: not sure why but plr = fixed to 200 when i debug

Comment: Using adjusted qualifier on `.Rows.Count` and *not* your original? I edited to show this solution should be *inside* `For` loop. When you `Debug.Print r`, does `r` increase with each iteration?

Comment: would like to know more about the following line of code, what these are doing

  .Range(.Cells(plr + 1, 1), _ 
           .Cells(plr + 200, 2) _

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! The `.Range(.Cells(...), .Cells(...))` is another way to define the range using R1C1 style and not letter and number concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Change the paste to
`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & plr + 1 & ":B" & plr + 201).PasteSpecial...`

Comment: Hi igttr, it didnt work :(

Comment: sorry, misplaced the colon (:), should have been before the B.  now corrected.

Comment: sorry igittr, still not working